# R sequence of dates and vectors

Tags: r, date

I'd like to recover a sequence of date which are between the 1st date of two vectors and the 2nd date of the same vectors, ....

Here is an example:

```
dates1 = as.Date(c('2015-10-01', '2015-03-27', '2015-05-20'))
dates2 = as.Date(c('2015-10-03', '2015-03-28', '2015-05-22'))
```

I'd like to recover this

```
'2015-10-01', '2015-10-02', '2015-10-03',  '2015-03-27' '2015-03-28',
'2015-05-20' '2015-05-21' '2015-05-22'
```

What is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map` to loop through the corresponding elements of `start` ('dates1') and `end` dates ('dates2') , use `seq`, `unlist` the `list` output to get a `vector` of dates.

```
lst <- Map(seq, dates1, dates2, MoreArgs=list(by='1 day'))
as.Date(unlist(lst), origin='1970-01-01')
#[1] "2015-10-01" "2015-10-02" "2015-10-03" "2015-03-27" "2015-03-28"
#[6] "2015-05-20" "2015-05-21" "2015-05-22"
```

Instead of `unlist`, we can use `do.call(c` as @bgoldst mentioned in the comments to avoid coercion of dates to 'numeric' value

```
 do.call('c', lst)
 #[1] "2015-10-01" "2015-10-02" "2015-10-03" "2015-03-27" "2015-03-28"
 #[6] "2015-05-20" "2015-05-21" "2015-05-22"
```

Or another option would be using `data.table` where we create a data.table with 'dates1' and 'dates2' as the columns, using `row number` as the grouping variable, we get the sequence of dates between 'dates1' and 'dates2', and extract the 'V1' column to get a vector of dates.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dates1, dates2)
DT[,seq(dates1, dates2, by= '1 day') , by = 1:nrow(DT)]$V1
#[1] "2015-10-01" "2015-10-02" "2015-10-03" "2015-03-27" "2015-03-28"
#[6] "2015-05-20" "2015-05-21" "2015-05-22"
```

Comment: I think instead of `as.Date(unlist(...),origin='1970-01-01')` it might be better to use `do.call(c,...)`.

Comment: @bgoldst Thanks, I forgot about it.

Answer (score 3):

akrun's solutions are very good (+1), but just for variety, here's an alternative approach you could take, using some addition, subtraction, `rep()`, and `sequence()`:

```
lengths <- dates2-dates1+1;
rep(dates1,lengths)+sequence(lengths)-1;
## [1] "2015-10-01" "2015-10-02" "2015-10-03" "2015-03-27" "2015-03-28" "2015-05-20" "2015-05-21" "2015-05-22"
```